# How to Implement FaceBook "Like-IT" Button in Iphone/Ipad?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, facebook-like

How to implement "Facebook ILikeIt" feature in Iphone and Ipad application? Help me out with step by step solution for implement this feature in the iphone application and requirement to implement this???

Thanks in advance !!!!

Gettting error in this line

```
static UIAccessibilityTraits *traitImage = nil, *traitButton = nil;
```

When I am selecting iPhone Device 2.2.1.

error: syntax error before '*' token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/)

[facebook IOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

Comment: Yes this is helpful for me.  Hey i am able to login with my credentials but how can i post a message on users wall he/she like's a our application.

In DemoApp there is a way to post a message on User's wall but i don't want to show that view which will shows UITextView to write a message on his/her wall.

I just want to post a message on user's wall after login like he/she like this application??

how can i do this?

Comment: @User532445: That another question ! Ask it !