# iLike it integration in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ipad

Hey i am able to login with my credentials but how can i post a message on users wall he/she like's a our application. In DemoApp there is a way to post a message on User's wall but i don't want to show that view which will shows UITextView to write a message on his/her wall. I just want to post a message on user's wall after login like he/she like this application?? how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Implement FaceBook "Like-IT" Button in Iphone/Ipad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482807/how-to-implement-facebook-like-it-button-in-iphone-ipad)

Comment: Ya i know it's repeated question but this is another thing it about to how i can i post message on my wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do an automatic 'Like'? Or are you just trying to post to the wall with a message?

To post to the current users wall, you'd need to make a graph call:

-(void) requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath 
                   andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params 
               andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod 
                 andDelegate:(id )delegate

And where graphPath is '/me/feed' & httpMethod is 'post'

The other parameters for this method are custom and up to your app...